# Use WSO2 on native desktop applications

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Can we use WSO2 for desktop applications, it does not have callback URL and don't want basic auth. Can you suggest how to handle this use case?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain your use case bit more? What is the scenario that you need to solve in the desktop application?

Comment: My application is a standalone desktop application WSO2 and my application will be deployed on a Private network. This application will not have a URL that WSO2 can redirect with code.

Basic auth with credentials is not safe as the credentials will be visible on the server side.

Looking for some help on using WSO2 in applications like these. Any directions will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the password grant or client credentials grant to authenticate your application.